# How to calculate overall computation time for a multi-threaded process

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, math, parallel-processing

I have a set of tasks, let's call it `T[]`, where each task `T[i]` needs a certain amount of time `t(T[i])` to be processed. The tasks are being processed in parallel by `X` threads (that is not to mean that multiple threads are co-working on a single task, but that multiple tasks are being processed by multiple threads, each thread doing one task, then the next, etc).

Now I want to calculate the expected overall time it will take to process all tasks. It's easy as long as `size(T[]) <= X` of course (i.e. the number of tasks is less than or equal to the number of threads), in this case the overall time equals the time of the slowest task.

But I'm quite lost for the case `X < size(T[])` (i.e. I have fewer threads than tasks). How would one calculate that in an elegant way?

edit: As asked by a commentator, we can assume the tasks queue is ordered by longest-running task first, shortest-running task last. Also, we can assume there is no pauses between tasks, and we can also neglect what the OS scheduler is doing.

Comment: The answer depends on the scheduling algorithm. For example, if you have 4 jobs each of 10s duration and one job of 100s duration and 4 threads, the duration will be 110s if the scheduler takes the first 4 jobs of 10s each as the first set and then runs the 100s job on its own in the second round. If the scheduler sorts by longest job first, the duration will be 100s.

Comment: right, I forgot to add this info. I have updated the post. So I know that tasks will be processed in the order of longest-running to shortest-running, but still I don't know how to calculate this.

Comment: You say "expected" time, but then it seems from the description the scheduling is deterministic. If it's indeed deterministic and the next task is assigned to the earliest free thread, it's easy to simulate. If it's not deterministic, the question needs editing to explain where the non-determinism comes in.

Comment: yeah, see my own edited answer. I actually ended up simulating it. it's not super accurate, but my tests showed it is accurate enough. for instance i did a run where it estimated 8 minutes, and it took 9. I think my answer about the simulation is the correct one for the question, but i cannot accept my own answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that the tasks are scheduled in the order that they're provided, and that each task goes to the first thread that's free. There's no meaningful non-determinism if these assumptions are correct -- a task may go to any of the threads that are free (if there's more than one), but this has no effect on the total running time.

In that case, we can simulate this using a min-heap of size X (where X is the number of threads), with the values in the heap representing the free time of one of the threads. For each task, we pop the earliest-free thread off the heap, and then push it back with the time it'll finish this new task.

After we've scheduled all tasks, we can take the largest value in the heap, which will be the time at which all tasks are completed.

This is relatively little code in Python:

```
import heapq

def compute_time(tasks, X):
    threads = [0] * X
    for t in tasks:
        heapq.heappush(threads, heapq.heappop(threads) + t)
    return max(threads)

print compute_time([3, 2, 1], 2)
print compute_time([5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1], 3)
```

Or in Java:

```
import java.util.*;

class Threads {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int totalTime1 = computeTotalTime(Arrays.asList(3, 2, 1), 2);
        System.out.println("totalTime1: " + totalTime1);

        int totalTime2 = computeTotalTime(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1), 3);
        System.out.println("totalTime2: " + totalTime2);
    }

    static int computeTotalTime(List<Integer> task, int threads) {
        PriorityQueue<Integer> q = new PriorityQueue<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) q.add(0);
        for (int t : task) q.add(q.poll() + t);
        int max = 0;
        while(!q.isEmpty()) max = q.poll();
        return max;
    }
}
```

Comment: OP mentions tasks are processed on *"longest first"* basis rather than in order presented.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The question also notes that the task queue is ordered by longest-first, so the code works as-is.

Comment: thanks. I wouldn't be aware of functions like your python code in Java, so the next best thing for me was to actually simulate it, see my own answer

Comment: Hmm, if you're only really interested in a Java solution, it'd be better to tag your question with the `java` tag. I don't really program in Java, but the Java equivalent of Python's minheap is java.util.PriorityQueue. I added a translation of the code.

Comment: Now that I have had a play with it, this is pretty neatly done - shame I can't upvote twice!

Comment: Thanks Paul, you're a genius! I will definatly try to remember this approach

Answer (score 0):

Simulating the test run is the solution when the execution order is (roughly) deterministic. I just took my real processing code, and replaced it with a simple Thread.sleep, while sleeping for the time the task is expected to take to process (just interpreted as milliseconds to scale it down). In the end, I just scaled up the time it took again and the result is quite good. I ran it with nearly 100 tasks with vastly different execution times, on 5 threads. It estimated 1 hour 39 minutes, and the real run was off only by 3 minutes.

```
            long startSim = currentTimeMillis();
            List<Integer> taskTimes = parallelTests.getRuntimesForAllTests(); // ordered from longest time
            ThreadPoolExecutor simulationExecutor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
            taskTimes.forEach(taskTime -> simulationExecutor.submit(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(taskTime); // this is really seconds, but we just take it as milliseconds
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }));
            simulationExecutor.shutdown();
            simulationExecutor.awaitTermination(1, MINUTES);
            long stopSim = currentTimeMillis();
            long timeNeeded = stopSim - startSim;
            // now just multiply it *1000 to scale it up to seconds again, and that's your result
```

Comment: For tasks [3, 2, 2, 2] on three threads, I think this will schedule the final task on the first thread giving an overall runtime of 5. But it should have runtime 4: the final task can be scheduled on one of the other two threads. In general, I find it hard to see why this code simulates a real system -- in reality a task will be held until a thread becomes free, and then assigned to it. In your code, that would correspond to assigning a task to the thread with the smallest total time rather than the smallest of the current and previous threads.

Comment: I guess you haven't seen what I edited at the beginning. Yes, I realized afterwards that it is flawed, and the solution was to run a test simulation. This gives me pretty precise estimates, I just ran a big run with nearly 100 tasks of very different runtime, on 5 threads. it estimated 1 hour 39 minutes and the real run was off by only a few minutes

Comment: No, I read it but misunderstood -- I thought you were saying the second solution was the less flawed one. Perhaps you could just delete the part of your answer you think is wrong.