# Python how to convert image into coordinates?

Tags: python, image, coordinates, bots, pixel

First of all sorry for my bad english :)

So what i'm trying to accomplish is to convert specific image into coordinates but unfortunately i can't find good and easy way to do it so that's why i'm asking here :)

Example i want to convert this image ( all off it or just specific parts) into coordinates:

[image]

I need this to move mouse accurately since there's many similar pixels on image, unless ofcourse anyone knows easier way ;)

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/49721962/2836621

Comment: You can use opencv for the purpose. Load the image using cv2.imread() method, you image will be loaded as a numpy array. you can find more info on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7762948/how-to-convert-an-rgb-image-to-numpy-array